# Use multiple connection in laravel queue

Tags: laravel-5, configuration, que

Using laravel 5.5, we need to use both Redis and SQS queues. Redis for our internal messaging and SQS for messages coming from a 3rd party.

`config/queue.php` has various connection information. The first key is the default connection. That default is the one used by `queue:work` artisan command.

```
'default' => 'redis',

'connections' => [
    'sqs' => [            
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key'    => env('ACCESS_KEY_ID', ''),
        'secret' => env('SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', ''),
        'prefix' => 'https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/account-id/',
        'queue'  => 'my-sqs-que'),
        'region' => 'us-west-1',
    ],


    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUE' , 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
```

The question is how can we use different queue connection for `queue:work`.

If `--queue=my-sqs-que` is supplied, with default connection set to redis, laravel looks under redis and obviously does not find `my-sqs-que`

Setting default to sqs will disable processing our internal messages.

Comment: Run multiple `queue:work` processes.

Comment: Running multiple processes still does not solve the problem. [at least within a single environment]. Each `queue:work` process still use `default` connection so we are still tied with either sqs or redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the connection when running `queue:work`, see [Specifying the Connection and Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker):

> You may also specify which queue connection the worker should utilize. The connection name passed to the work command should correspond to one of the connections defined in your  config/queue.php configuration file:

```
php artisan queue:work redis
```

You will need to setup the corresponding connections per queue, as well.

> However, any given queue connection may have multiple "queues" which may be thought of as different stacks or piles of queued jobs.

Comment: Jobs are created as configured, but listener is connection default connection, how to make connection dynamic for listener ?